# Update table column based on columns in other table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have `dim_table` with the columns:

```
item_key, client_id, date, notes, old_key
```

And a `fact_table`:

```
user_key, trans_key, item_key, ref_number,date
```

I have to update `fact_table` where `item_key` is NOT EQUAL to `dim_table.item_key`.
But `dim_table.old_key` is equal to the existing keys in `fact_table.item_key`.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
update fact_table
SET fact_table.item_key = dim_table.item_key
where
fact_table.item_key = dim_table.old_key
and fact_table.item_key <> dim_table.item_key
```

> ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "dim_table"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Missing `FROM` item (as posted by @Brandon).
- Column in the `SET` clause table-qualified, which is invalid (as commented by @Rohit).
- Logic contradicts description:`<>` and `=` switched in `WHERE` clause.

I also simplified with table aliases:

```
UPDATE fact_table f
SET    item_key = d.item_key
FROM  dim_table d
WHERE  f.item_key <> d.old_key
AND    f.item_key = d.item_key;
```

[Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html)

> Do not include the table's name in the specification of a target
>   column — for example, `UPDATE tab SET tab.col = 1` is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the from part of your update statement:

```
update fact_table
SET item_key = dim_table.item_key
FROM dim_table
where
fact_table.item_key = dim_table.old_key
and fact_table.item_key <> dim_table.item_key
```

Comment: You should not list the target table the `from` clause. That creates a cartesian join with itself. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html

Comment: Ok I edited it. I don't normally do it this way anyway, I normally use an alias with an inner join. Was just trying to keep it consistent with the original statement.

Comment: The query will only work if you remove. fact_table from from the SET. update fact_table.

SET item_key = dim_table.item_key
FROM dim_table
where
fact_table.item_key = dim_table.old_key
and fact_table.item_key <> dim_table.item_key